# How exactly does induced Scalp Hypothermia prevent alopecia (hair loss) during chemo therapy?

Tags: scalp, chemotherapy, alopecia, hypothermia, cancer

> Recent studies <sup>1</sup> of women getting chemo for early-stage breast cancer have found that at least half of the women using one of these newer devices lost less than half of their hair. <sup>2</sup>

Scalp Hypothermia sounds like almost freezing the hair and hair follicle. But it probably isn't. What temperatures are actually used for that? And how exactly does induced Scalp Hypothermia prevent alopecia (hair loss) during chemo therapy and do scalp hypothermia not affect the brain?

---

<sup>1 https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/28939291</sup>
<sup>2 https://www.oncoreahmedabad.com/cool-capsscalp-hypothermia/</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All chemical reactions including killing cancer cells with poisons occur at approximately twice the rate per ten degrees. So reducing the scalp by ten degrees while chemo is occurring will reduce the rate of poisoned hair follicles by half during the procedure.

https://www.chemguide.co.uk/physical/basicrates/temperature.html

Comment: Interesting answer, but do you have any references to support it? You know that's required here.

Comment: Chemical reactions doubling every ten degrees is something in the back of my brain from long ago. I'm sure it's on the internet somewhere. I'll have a look. Yep.  Added. https://www.chemguide.co.uk/physical/basicrates/temperature.html